# What does TEST_LOGS in automake do?

Tags: automake

The Automake Manual says

15.2.3 Parallel Test Harness

You can set the TEST_LOGS variable. By default, this variable is computed at
make run time from the value of TESTS as described above. For example, you
can use the following:

```
set x subset*.log; shift
env TEST_LOGS="foo.log $*" make -e check
```

What does setting TEST_LOGS do? It is read only in the Makefile file and write only in the shell.

TEST_LOGS contains the name of all .log files. I get that. What happens if the user changes one or all the names. Suppose Makefile looks something like:

```
TESTS = foo.exe
```

Then we have

```
TEST_LOGS = foo.log
```

And the user sets this to

env TEST_LOGS=bar.log make -e check

What on earth does this mean?

And the examples with TEST_EXTENSIONS and duplicate base names (test cases
with extensions removed, like TESTS = test.sh test.pl and TEST_EXTENSIONS =
.pl .sh) grows even more complex.

Any idea?

And what does

```
set x subset*.log; shift
```

have to do with the example. It looks like a fragment of some script erroneously put it the example. Certainly 'shift' doesn't apply here.